# Rounding to nearest .00 or .05 instead of .01 or .02 etc in decimals

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have this rounding where I am trying to round the decimal price so that the decimals always round to either .00 or .05 (using this rule .00,.01,.02,.03,.04 = .00 and .05,.06,.07,.08,.09 = .05) - but right now with the below code it also returns .01, .02 etc in the decimal numbers.

```
 // 2 is the number of decimals that it should return.
 decimal unitPriceFloored = System.Math.Round(price, 2, System.MidpointRounding.ToZero);
```

How can I change it so that it round the price to .00 or .05 in the decimals?
Just to clarify - this should work the same way with .10 and .15 etc. (all 2 decimal comma numbers)

Comment: Multiply be 20, round, then divide by 20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a built-in function to do this. Here's a way:

```
for(decimal m = 1m; m < 1.2m; m = m + 0.01m)
   WriteLine( $"{m} -> {Math.Truncate(m) + (int)(((m - Math.Truncate(m))*100)/5) * 0.05m }");
```

This prints:

```
1 -> 1.00 
1.01 -> 1.00
1.02 -> 1.00
1.03 -> 1.00
1.04 -> 1.00
1.05 -> 1.05
1.06 -> 1.05
1.07 -> 1.05
1.08 -> 1.05
1.09 -> 1.05
1.10 -> 1.10
1.11 -> 1.10
1.12 -> 1.10
1.13 -> 1.10
1.14 -> 1.10
1.15 -> 1.15
1.16 -> 1.15
1.17 -> 1.15
1.18 -> 1.15
1.19 -> 1.15
```